# Handle DWORD in Python with ctypes and windll. Pointer in Python?

Tags: python, delphi

I am currently working on a project to control an external device through a pre-packaged dynamic link library and I must say, the ctypes library definitely make life much easier! However some functions I used that is imported from Delphi require as Parameter a Handle from type DWORD. I ran into some trouble trying to pass an integer as argument. In the Delphi code it works just fine by passing a variable from type longword as argument. Belows are some code fragments:

Variable definition and passing onto function in Delphi. The function DmxProOpen take the Serial number as argument and return the handle to pass on to other functions:

```
function DmxProOpen (cSerNo: pchar; var dHandle: DWORD): integer;
         stdcall; external 'DmxPro.dll'; // function definition in delphi
dLocalHandle : longword;
procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick (Sender: TObject);
const
  SERNO : pchar = 'EN096445';

begin
  lblStatus.Caption:=inttostr( DmxProOpen(SERNO,dLocalHandle) );
end;
```

here is the error in Python:

```
  File "C:\Users\Labor-Laptop\Desktop\2-ARRI-DOWLIGHT\USB-DMX-DLL\USB-DMX-DLL\Ansteuerung Python.py", line 33, in <module>
    printOpenReturnValue(DLLIMPORT.DmxProOpen(SERNO, dLocalHandle))

OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

And here is what i am trying to do:

```
import ctypes
DLLIMPORT = ctypes.WinDLL("DmxPro.dll")
SERNO= 'EN096445' #Serial number
dLocalHandle= 0
printOpenReturnValue(DLLIMPORT.DmxProOpen(SERNO, dLocalHandle))
```

I also try to import DWORD type with the from ctype import DWORD but get an error like below:

```
  File "C:\Users\Labor-Laptop\Desktop\2-ARRI-DOWLIGHT\USB-DMX-DLL\USB-DMX-DLL\Ansteuerung Python.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ctypes import DWORD

ImportError: cannot import name 'DWORD' from 'ctypes' (C:\Users\Labor-Laptop\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py)
```

I really appreciate the help! Thanks a bunch in advance and have a nice day!
Update: I try to find a way to pass a pointer to the function, but as i keep looking on internet, there is just no way to specify a pointer in python. What should i do?
Update 2:
I have tried the c_char_p as well as c_void_p but does not work:

```
 printOpenReturnValue(DLLIMPORT.DmxProOpen(SERNO, dLocalHandle))

ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

Comment: You need to pass a *pointer* to `dLocalHandle`, not its value.

Comment: yep i know that the Handle itself is a pointer. But how do i specify one in python? I'm still new to Python. I thought it was going to work because in Delphi they just use Longword and it is the equivalent of unsigned integer in C++

Comment: It works in Delphi because of the `var` keyword.

Comment: thank you for your answer! However i cannot find a way to use pointers in Python... :(

Comment: A simple search gives [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference).

Comment: Oh well really thanks a lot!

Comment: You really need to start using argtypes and restype.

Comment: yeah thanks for the advice @DavidHeffernan I am still really new to python and programming in general so i am still learning a lot!